# How can I access the instance of an object of another class in my actual class?

Tags: c++, object

I #included the highscore file to my header. now I am creating an object of it in my submarine.cpp, but I can not access it anyway. When I try, writing "highscore." to show me some of its methods, it doesn't show anything and tells me my variable that I declared before is unused.

```
Submarine::Submarine(QGraphicsItem* parent):QObject (),         
QGraphicsPixmapItem (parent)
{
Highscore *highscore = new Highscore;
QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(die()));
timer->start(50);
}

void Submarine::doSomething()
{
highscore->increase(); (HERE)
```

how can I access my highscore in methods of my Submarine class???? Do I have to do something more in the header file??

Comment: You can use the member access operator.

Comment: When accessing members by pointer, write `highscore->` instead of `highscore.`.

Comment: `highscore` is only a local variable in the `Submarine` constructor. Once you leave that function, you have no way to access it. So, you need to either assign the `new`ly created pointer to a member variable or make `highscore` a member variable and initialize it by `highscore = new Highscore;` where `highscore` is declared in the header as a member of `Submarine`. Then you can access it anywhere in the class.

Comment: @Sergey You're right. I wrote it that way, because my compiler corrects it automatically. I've edited that part now in the question. 

Do you see something else to solve this?

Comment: @Apbln see callyalater's answer. You should declare `Highscore *highscore` as a member of `Submarine` class, not a local variable in `Submarine` constructor.

Comment: What you have is a [memory leak](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Memory_leaks). So, be careful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a memory leak in your constructor:

```
Submarine::Submarine(QGraphicsItem* parent):QObject (),         
QGraphicsPixmapItem (parent)
{
Highscore *highscore = new Highscore; // <-- Your problem is here
QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(die()));
timer->start(50);
} // <-- the highscore and timer pointers go out of scope here
```

At the end of the constructor, the pointer to the Highscore instance goes out of scope and is lost.  You need to save it in a member variable of your Submarine class in order to use it subsequently in the doSomething() method.  The same issue applies to the QTimer* timer pointer created in the constructor body.